# How to avoid that an installed package is reinstalled every time an used runtime package is recompiled?

Tags: delphi, design-time, delphi-ide

I have a *designtime package* which is installed in the IDE and uses classes and functions defined in a *runtime package*.

Each time I compile or build the *runtime package*, it seems that the *designtime package* is automatically reinstalled.

This operation starts after pressing the "Ok" button of the "Compiling window" and takes a several seconds.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid that. The designtime package depends on the runtime package. When you recompile the runtime package it has to be unloaded and reloaded to make the new compilation effective. Unloading the runtime package requires all dependent packages to be unloaded before. At least the IDE is clever enough to automatically reload the dependent packages after loading the new runtime package.

Comment: But you may always create a design time package which does not depend on the run-time one. Just add all the units of the runtime package to the contains section of your designtime package and remove your runtime package from the requires section of you design-time package.